maas boot resources create fails with '[errno 2] no such file or directory'
I use maas 3.5/stable and use root login ubuntu 24.04.01.
Abd used this cmd to building an image:
packer init
PACKER_LOG=1 packer build -var 'rhel9_iso_path=/PATH/TO/rhel-baseos-9.1-x86_64-dvd.iso' .

Then used this cmd to uploading an image to MAAS:
maas $PROFILE boot-resources create \
    name='rhel/9-custom' title='RHEL 9 Custom' \
    architecture='amd64/generic' filetype='tgz' \
    content@=rhel9.tar.gz

But failed with:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rhel9.tar.gz'

The file does exists:
root@test:~/packer-maas/rhel9# ll
total 11749176
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root        4096 Dec 17 08:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root        4096 Dec 16 07:23 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root        4096 Dec 16 07:23 http/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root         421 Dec 16 07:23 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        2205 Dec 16 07:23 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 11085742080 Jun  3  2024 rhel-9.4-x86_64-dvd.iso
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        1816 Dec 16 07:23 rhel9.pkr.hcl
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   945379395 Dec 16 09:45 rhel9.tar.gz*

I tried chmod 777 -R rhel9.tar.gz, change dir to /home, /media, /tmp,  /root, ~/ still failed.
This problem also occurs in uploading sles15, windows server 2025, vmware-esxi 8.0.
